# Web API: HTTP verb 'OPTIONS'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, beta, http-options-method

Is there any support in the asp.net mvc 4 web api beta for the HTTP verb 'OPTIONS'?
The framework does not automatically send a response. I think you have to do this by yourselve. But is there a method like: GetVerbsForUrl("http://server.com/api/values");   ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a feature called ApiExplorer which can provide Web Api descriptions. You can see more details here:

- [Introducing IApiExplorer/ApiExplorer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yaohuang1/archive/2012/05/13/asp-net-web-api-introducing-iapiexplorer-apiexplorer.aspx)
- [Generating a Web API help page using ApiExplorer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yaohuang1/archive/2012/05/21/asp-net-web-api-generating-a-web-api-help-page-using-apiexplorer.aspx)

Comment: This feature is not on the beta, it's on the RC though.

Comment: Yea, i know this feature. It sounds like there is no build-in support for the options verb. I have to do it by myself. Does the ApiExplorer uses reflection? (I am asking due to performance)

Comment: I implemented a generic solution using Http message handlers and Api Explorer http://www.jefclaes.be/2012/09/supporting-options-verb-in-aspnet-web.html